# Randoms:" C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm working on VS2010 and while I'm trying to compile my solution which have around 37-40 projects I randomly receive this error message. and every time is point to a different location in the code:

`2>D:\Sources\XXX\Database\SqlResult.cpp : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

2>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\p2pragma.c', line 160)

2>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.

2>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++

2>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information`

What can cause this error? and how can I avoid it?
If more info is needed, please let me know what.

Thanks.

Comment: it was just one time there. since then I tried 3 times to "clean" and "rebuild" the solution and each time i get the same error with a different file.

Comment: This is a bug in the compiler. Likely, it gets confused over a `#pragma` in your code. Can you show some of it?

Comment: Try removing code until you no longer get the error.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that... so I guess there is no magical building-parameter I can adjust to avoid that...

Comment: Try disabling concurrent builds, that removes scope for a lot of compiler bugs

Comment: I had that error once. Was caused by failing memory. Maybe you should memtest.

Comment: that's actually make scenes, I just had received a 2 "new" GB to my working computer. Thanks.